Rails 7 with turbo - some requests on Chrome/FF doesn't work correctly
It happens only on Chrome/Firefox - on Safari everything works fine.
I noticed that some requests (eg. file upload) don't work correctly after moving to turbo (from turbolinks). Request:
patch https://my.local.domain/profile/set_logo

returns (on localhost):
HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>

and on staging it reloads the whole page and doesn't upload the file.
It fails only after changing from turbolinks to turbo.
Any ideas?

Nope, no ideas.  You haven't given much to work with.  Please post some of the view to give people some idea of what you are doing.

This problem may be related to turbo form submission policy:
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission
Turbo is expecting to recieve a redirect after every form submission. To disable this behavior add data-turbo="false" to your form.
